# Pérdida de calidad visual en esquinas de Border al usar WindowChrome

Tags: c#, xaml, wpf

Estoy creando una ventana en WPF utilizando WindowChrome de la librería `Microsoft.Windows.Shell` con la intención de obtener una ventana personalizada sin los marcos de ventana de Windows y no perder rendimiento gráfico.

Sin embargo, el diseño lleva esquinas redondeadas, pero estas no se ven a como desearía, se ven pixeladas.
[image: Actual vs. Resultado deseado]

Además, este es el código del WindowChrome:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:shell="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/shell"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BlackXells.Locker.UI"
    x:Class="BlackXells.Locker.UI.Dashboard"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Locker" MinHeight="550" MinWidth="950" Height="525" Width="1036" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Icon="/Locker;component\Resources\locker-logo.ico">

<shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <shell:WindowChrome CornerRadius="20" ResizeBorderThickness="6" GlassFrameThickness="0"/>
</shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
<Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" CornerRadius="20" BorderBrush="#FFC8C8C8" BorderThickness="1">
    <Grid/>
  </Border>
</Window>
```

Además, si no utilizo `WindowChrome` y establezco `WindowStyle = None` y `ResizeMode = NoResize` obtengo el resultado deseado, no obstante pierdo algunas funcionalidades que deseo tener (animación de minimizado, entre otros), además de que se reduce el rendimiento de la ventana.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes obtener un resultado mucho mejor siguiendo estas recomendaciones

1. No utilices **Microsoft.Windows.Shell** ya que desde las últimas versiones de WPF se incluye en el **presentation framework**, en su lugar agrega este using en el xaml

   ```
   xmlns:chrome="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Shell;assembly=PresentationFramework"
   ```
2. Ahora modifica el estilo de la ventana, puntualmente la propiedad `WindowChrome.WindowChrome` estableciendo los siguientes valores en la configuración:

   ```
   <Window.Style>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
       <Setter Property="chrome:WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
           <Setter.Value>
               <chrome:WindowChrome CaptionHeight="6"
                                   CornerRadius="20"
                                   GlassFrameThickness="0"
                                   NonClientFrameEdges="None"
                                   ResizeBorderThickness="6"
                                   UseAeroCaptionButtons="False"/>
           </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
   </Style>
   </Window.Style>
   ```
3. Luego si dibujas el contenido el cual puede ser el que nos mostraste arriba aunque ajustando el radio

   ```
   <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="#FFC8C8C8" BorderThickness="1">
       <Grid/>
   </Border>
   ```

Con esto lograrás un resultado más cercano a lo que quieres.

[image: Resultado optimizado]

#### Código completo:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        xmlns:shell="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/shell"
        xmlns:chrome="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Shell;assembly=PresentationFramework"
        mc:Ignorable="d" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="chrome:WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <chrome:WindowChrome CaptionHeight="6"
                                    CornerRadius="20"
                                    GlassFrameThickness="0"
                                    NonClientFrameEdges="None"
                                    ResizeBorderThickness="6"
                                    UseAeroCaptionButtons="False"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>

    <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="#FFC8C8C8" BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid/>
    </Border>

</Window>
```